# Adding a backslash at the end of the each line in Vim

Tags: vim

How do I insert a space + backslash at the end of the all lines in my Vim editor?

Comment: Go to the end of the line, add space + backslash, go to the next line, add space + backslash, ... repeat. What was the problem?

Comment: here you go:   `:%s/$/ \\/g`

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303032/how-to-add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line-in-vim

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
:%norm A \
```

or

```
:%s/$/ \\/
```