# vi VIM How to append line to itself?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, append, match

I want to append the entire content of the line (excluding the ending newline) to the line itself.
I saw this solution `:%s/$/\*/g` here:
[How can I add a string to the end of each line in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594448/how-can-i-add-to-the-end-of-each-line-in-vim)

But it is appending the character * to the lines. I tried both `:%s/$/*/g` and `:%s/$/\*/g` but the same result.

I am using
  VIM - Vi IMproved version 7.3.46

PS: it seems, as a new user i am not allowed to post this question as a comment there.
thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once again, command mode is vastly underrated:

```
:t.|-j
```

DONE

**Update** I saw in another comment that you want to do this for a range. This is easy too. See below

This is basically the Ex equivalent of `yyPJx` **except**

1. It won't clobber any registers
2. Won't shift the "0-"9 registers
3. Won't affect the current search and/or search history (like in the `:%s` based answer)
4. Can be immediately repeated by doing `@:` - no macros, no mappings :)
5. will result in atomic undo (whereas the `yyPJx` approach would result in 3 separate undo steps)

Explanation:

- `:t` is synonym for `:copy`
- `:j` is short for `:join`
- `:-j` is short for `:-1join`, meaning: join the previous line with it's successor

Note: If you wanted to preserve leading whitespace (like `yyPgJx` instead of `yyPgJx`) use:

```
:t.|-j!
```

**Update** for repeats, with a visual selection type

```
:'<,'>g/^/t.|-j
```

Which repeats it for every line in the visual selection. (Of course, `:'<,'>` is automatically inserted in visual mode). Another benefit of this approach is that you can easily specify a filter for which lines to duplicate:

```
:g/foo/t.|-j
```

Will 'duplicate' all lines containing 'foo' in the current buffer (see windo, bufdo, argdo to scale this to a plethora of buffers without breaking a sweat).

Comment: It is really more helpful than the previous answer, so i accepted this. @sehe: "command mode is vastly underrated" this is a really insightful comment.

Comment: @TemPora Thanks for the kind words. Command mode takes getting used to. Usually as long as you have linewise operations there is a command mode equivalent for doing things (e.g. `%>|%y+|undo` is convenient for posting on SO :))

Answer (score 6):

You can use this substitution:

```
:s/^.*$/&&
```

- `^.*$` means "whatever (`.*`) is between the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the line".
- `&` represents the matched text so we are substituting the whole line with itself followed by itself again.

***edit***

Ingo's comment is spot-on: `:s/.*/&&` does the same with less typing.

Comment: Wow, 3 different answers in a couple of minutes... you guys are really quick today :-)

Comment: You don't need the anchoring `^...$`, as `.` will match anything (except the newline) by default: `:s/.*/&&`.

Comment: I have added an answer with 4 fewer keystrokes, **and** it doesn't affect search pattern history. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13280126/85371 - Eternal praise for Ex mode commands

Comment: @sehe: I'm only starting to use Ex commands myself. I've introduced `:m` in my daily usage recently and it kicks ass. Your answer is awesome.

Comment: @romainl Cheers :) `g//m$` is nifty, so many times for me too

Answer (score 1):

Go to the line you want to append to itself.
Then type:  `0y$$p`

Explanation:
0 - for going to the start of the line
y$ - yank everything from the cursor to the end of the line
$ - for going to the end of the line
p - for "putting" the yank buffer

Comment: Might be worth adding `^` to the beginning of that.

Comment: Instead of `$p`, you can also just use `P`, as the cursor is at the beginning after the yank.

Comment: I knew that but I want to do it for a bunch of lines with a command something like `:%s/$/<regex>`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh - if you wanted repeats, **do** have a look at my Ex answer: `:g/^/t.|-j` or `g/pattern/t.|-j` for specific lines (matching `pattern`)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try: `yyPJx`.

This will append a copy of the current line to it's self.

You could even:

`noremap ,l yyPJx`

In your `.vimrc` if you want to map a keystroke to accomplish this.

Comment: It maybe worth noting that `J` will adjust the white space by removing the indent and inserting up to 2 spaces. Depending on your needs `gJ` might be worth a look.

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks Peter, `gJ` definitely could be the right choice, depending on requirements as you say.